# How do I connect to MySQL DB using a jump host with Sequel Pro

Tags: ssh, sequelpro

I want to connect to my MySQL database as below

`[A: local host] -> [B: jump host] -> [C: target host] => [D: MySQL host]`

Is it possible with Sequel Pro?